# Vue Nuxt: How to make dynamic routes in Nuxt

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

Im new to vue and nuxt but i will use it with a node backend that has this route to the product section (im making a ecommerce), that its almost working 100% (the page parameter i didnt try to implement)

```
router.route("/products/create/page/:pageNow?/search/:searchTerm?/categories/:categoryName?/size/:sizeName?/stickers/:stickerName?") // im planing to have the minimum price parameter, all the parameter excluind search are an array, can have multipe values
```

Im planning to do this layout (the banner is okay i can handle it)

[image]

I just wanna know how to handle the parameters, if i will had to use vuex or not, im really knew on vue and nuxt. (im using nuxt with typescript and tailwind)

Comment: It seems like you are trying to create a deep nested dynamic pages for your store, right? For the state management library. I would suggest using pinia instead of vuex since pinia is the relatively new state management for vue/nuxt.

Comment: thanks! i will use pinia for update the route variables and then the page right? also i "simplified" my route to "/find/page/:pageNum?/:searchTerm?/:categoryNames?/:sizeNames?/:stickerNames?/:min?/:max?"